# showDialog problem inside tabbed activity

Tags: android, dialog, tabbed-view

I have a tabhost with 2 tabs inside my main activity, for the 2nd tab i added a list view intent as content.
Everything is working fine. 
Now I have overriden `onCreateDialog()` method in the list view (2nd tab's), when i made a call to `showDialog(MY_DIALOG);` method `onCreateDialog()` is getting called but I'm getting a warning in the LogCat like

```
"WARN/InputManagerService(58): Window already focused, ignoring 
focus gain of:  com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44ee6948"
```

Can anybody help me how to show the dialog box inside tabhost's activity.

//edit

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, " " +CLASSTAG+ " onCreateDialog(): +++ START +++");
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_MY_TYPES: {
        Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, " " +CLASSTAG+ " onCreateDialog(): DIALOG_MY_TYPES");
        CharSequence[] items = {"option1", "option2", "option3"};
        builder.setTitle("Select").setItems(items,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    Log.d(CLASSTAG, "item selected = " + item);
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Log.d(Constants.LOGTAG, " "+CLASSTAG+" Cancel button is clicked");
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); 
    }

}//switch
alert = builder.create();
Log.v(Constants.LOGTAG, " " +CLASSTAG+ " onCreateDialog(): +++ END +++");
return super.onCreateDialog(id);                
}
```

Thanks in advance.
-Nehatha

Comment: Can you show the code for `onCreateDialog` method.

Comment: @Tanmay, updated the original question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return super.onCreateDialog(id);` to `return alert;`.  I assume some other part of your Activity is calling showDialog(int).  If not, then you'll either want to do so, or call the show method on the returned Dialog from onCreateDialog(id).